# Change label in parent viewcontroller container

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using a container to show a UIPageViewController on it. As you can see in my image I got a grey bar under the navigation bar with a white Label on it. I want to change this label in the "Page Scroll View Controller", how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you connected that `UILabelView` to the property in `ViewController`? If not, then you have to do that first.

Declare the property like:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *blablabla;
```

Now, after connecting that property to the outlet. You can access it in same `ViewController` like following:

```
self.blablabla.text = @"your text goes here";
```

Let me know if you are facing any problem!

Comment: I need to be able to change the label in the "Page Scroll View Controller", not in the normal View Controller

Comment: Are you able to add `UILabel` to `PageScrollViewController`?

Comment: I cannot add the UILabel to the PageScrollViewController class

Comment: So, that was my point. You can't do that. You should consider adding it in viewcontroller's view.